# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

Error in title. What's going wrong?
Attempting to initialize Temperature object with a hash. If I just do

```
puts Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_fahrenheit
```

then it works fine and returns 122.0

But

```
Temperature.new(:f => 50)
```

returns an error.

```
class Temperature
  attr_accessor :f, :c

  @temp = {:f => 32, :c => 0}

  def initialize(params)
    if params[:f] != nil
      self.class.from_fahrenheit(params[:f])

    else 
      self.class.from_celsius(params[:c])
    end
  end

  def self.from_fahrenheit(temp)
   @temp[:f] = temp 
   @temp[:c] = ((temp - 32.0)/1.8).round(1)

    return @temp
  end

  def self.from_celsius(temp)
    @temp[:c] = temp
    @temp[:f] = (temp * 1.8 + 32).round(1)

    return @temp
  end  

  def in_fahrenheit
    @temp[:f]
  end

  def in_celsius
    @temp[:c]
  end


end

class Hash
  def in_fahrenheit
    self[:f]
  end

  def in_celsius
    self[:c]
  end
end

puts Temperature.from_celsius(50).in_celsius

tempo = Temperature.new(:f => 50)
tempo.in_fahrenheit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error message says. You are calling `[]=` on `@temp` in a `Temperature` instance, which is `nil` by default because you have not assigned anything to it anywhere.

Comment: But my fourth line is `@temp = {:f => 32, :c => 0}`. @temp is initialized. I'm still very confused.

Comment: You initialized it for the `Temperature` class, but not for its instances.

Comment: I thought @variablename makes it an instance variable. My understanding of scope is breaking down. ughh....it hurts.

Comment: Notice that a class is also an instance (of the `Class` class). You made an instance variable for an instance of the `Class` class (`Temperature`), but not for the instances of that instance of the `Class` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize instance variable in a class body, as you did. You should do it in a constructor, and because you have three constructors, your code should look like this:

```
class Temperature
  def initialize(params)
    @temp = {:f => 32, :c => 0}
    if params[:f] != nil
      self.class.from_fahrenheit(params[:f])
    else 
      self.class.from_celsius(params[:c])
    end
  end

  def self.from_fahrenheit(temp)
    @temp = {}
    @temp[:f] = temp 
    @temp[:c] = ((temp - 32.0)/1.8).round(1)

    return @temp
  end

  def self.from_celsius(temp)
    @temp = {}
    @temp[:c] = temp
    @temp[:f] = (temp * 1.8 + 32).round(1)

    return @temp
  end  

  def in_fahrenheit
    @temp[:f]
  end

  def in_celsius
    @temp[:c]
  end


end
```

Comment: Your phrase "class instance" is not clear. Do you mean an instance of a `Class` class, or do you mean an instance of some class? If it is the latter, then your description is misleading.